# nested dictionary to pandas Dataframe within a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a nested Dictionary list which is...

```
order = [
    {
    'order_id' : 1,
    'status' : 'processing',
    'line_items': [
                    {
                    'product_id': 2,
                    'product_name' : 'mango'
                    },

                    {
                    'product_id':4,
                    'product_name': 'orange'
                    }
                  ],

    }, 
    {
    'order_id' : 2,
    'status' : 'processing',
    'line_items': [
                    {
                    'product_id': 3,
                    'product_name' : 'banana'
                    }
                  ]
    },                  
]
```

I want to get a Dataframe like this...

```
    order_id    status       line_items
0     1         processing    product_id: 2, 
                              product_name: mango
                              product_id:4
                              product_name: orange

1     2         processing    product_id': 3 
                              product_name: banana
```

I have tried like this

```
df_order = pd.DataFrame(order)
```

and other various ways but could not solve the problem.

Comment: Where did the jackfruit come from, it's supposed to be a banana no?

Comment: yes. sorry for that mistake

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.json_normalize`. I think you should stop there. I've taken the liberty of trying to make it look more like your desired output, but I think that's a terrible way of representing the data compared to what it looked like before `.set_index(...).stack()`.

```
df = (pd.json_normalize(order, ['line_items'], ['order_id', 'status'])
        .set_index(['order_id', 'status'])
        .stack())
df.index.names = ['order_id', 'status', 'line_items']
print(df)
```

Output.

```
order_id  status      line_items
1         processing  product_id           2
                      product_name     mango
                      product_id           4
                      product_name    orange
2         processing  product_id           3
                      product_name    banana
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. it works. I have tried it for 2 days yet could not get any idea. Thanks again